# Load content with URL update and default content

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, plugins, jquery-load

I have a jQuery plugin that loads content into a certain div. Ignore the drawmap function at the beginning. It only serves in one of the pages. I'm trying to load content into the div while updating the url (not redirecting). For example, if I click on About Us the url will show: calstateautoparts.com/beta/aboutus.html. If I click on contact us the url will show calstateautoparts.com/beta/contactus.html.

Also, I would like to have the plugin load a page in the div by default, home.html. How do I make both of these changes in my code?

You can see the live site at: http://calstateautoparts.com/beta

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
    function drawmap(){
        new Maplace({
                    locations: [
                        {
                            lat: 33.8583,
                            lon: -117.8678,
                            title: 'Anaheim',
                            html: [
                                '<h3>Anaheim</h3>',
                                '<p>1361 N RedGum St, Anaheim CA 92806<br>(714) 630-5954</p>'
                            ].join(''),
                            zoom: 8
                        },
                        {
                            lat: 34.2358,
                            lon: -118.5739,
                            title: 'Chatsworth',
                            html: [
                                '<h3>Chatsworth</h3>',
                                '<p>20233 Corisco St, Chatsworth CA 91311<br>(818) 998-3001</p>'
                            ].join(''),
                            zoom: 8
                        },
                        {
                            lat: 32.8142,
                            lon: -117.1247,
                            title: 'San Diego',
                            html: [
                                '<h3>San Diego</h3>',
                                '<p>4000 Ruffin Road Suite K, San Diego CA 92123<br>(858) 292-1622</p>'
                            ].join(''),
                            zoom: 8
                        }
                        ,
                        {
                            lat: 34.9137,
                            lon: -120.4632,
                            title: 'Santa Maria',
                            html: [
                                '<h3>Santa Maria</h3>',
                                '<p>1459 W. Fairway Dr., Santa Maria CA 93455<br>(805) 922-4445</p>'
                            ].join(''),
                            zoom: 8
                        }
                        ,
                        {
                            lat: 34.5011,
                            lon: -117.3279,
                            title: 'Victorville',
                            html: [
                                '<h3>Victorville</h3>',
                                '<p>15400-B Tamarack Road, Victorville CA 92392<br>(760) 243-5666</p>'
                            ].join(''),
                            zoom: 8
                        }
                        ,
                        {
                            lat: 36.1605,
                            lon: -115.1050,
                            title: 'Las Vegas',
                            html: [
                                '<h3>Las Vegas</h3>',
                                '<p>3101 Builders Ave., Las Vegas, NV 89101<br>(702) 452-2440</p>'
                            ].join(''),
                            zoom: 8
                        }
                        ,
                        {
                            lat: 33.1677,
                            lon: -117.2202,
                            title: 'Vista',
                            html: [
                                '<h3>Vista</h3>',
                                '<p>2055 Thibodo Rd, Vista CA 92081<br>(760) 599-0791</p>'
                            ].join(''),
                            zoom: 8
                        }
                        ,
                        {
                            lat: 33.6224,
                            lon: -117.7194,
                            title: 'Laguna Hills',
                            html: [
                                '<h3>Laguna Hills</h3>',
                                '<p>23561 Ridge Route Suite P, Laguna Hills CA 92653<br>(949) 699-3308</p>'
                            ].join(''),
                            zoom: 8
                        }
                        ,
                        {
                            lat: 34.4245,
                            lon: -118.4998,
                            title: 'Santa Clarita',
                            html: [
                                '<h3>Santa Clarita</h3>',
                                '<p>26846 Oak Ave Unit R, Santa Clarita CA 91315<br>(661) 424-9396</p>'
                            ].join(''),
                            zoom: 8
                        }
                    ],
                   map_div: '#gmap-list',
                   controls_type: 'list',
                controls_title: 'Choose a location:'
                }).Load();
    }
    $('.menuitem').click(function(e){
        $('#contentarea').load(this.href, $(this).data('loadfunc') || null);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#contactus').data({loadfunc: drawmap});
});
        </script>
```